# Mmorpg с клиентом на сайте

Tags: flash, разработка-игр, javascript

Online Mmorpg 3D игра с клиентом на сайте реально или извращение и фантазия дурачка?
Есть же игры с клиентом на сайте.
Реально ли осуществить такую игру? В какую сторону копать при выборе языка, для написания 3D Browser mmorpg?

Comment: Конечно реально. Можно даже и без флеша. webgl обернутая в threejs творит чудеса.

Comment: были уже проекты с использованием юнити, на сайте юнити вроде бы есть ссылки и обзоры.

Answer (score 2):

[Drakensang](http://www.drakensang-online.ru/)

[Dark Orbit](http://www.darkorbit.ru/)

[Battlestar Galactica Online](http://ru.battlestar-galactica.bigpoint.ru/)

Первая в Java,третья на Unity, во вторую не играл.

Comment: А  можно парочку ссылок на исходники 3D игры для сайта на Java.

Answer (score 0):

1. реально
2. реально
3. three.js и иже с ними - на клиенте, node.js - на сервере

Comment: А есть исходники таких чтучек ну как бы в деле всё равно хоть крестики нолики онлайн. Главное посмотреть код и как реализовано

Comment: идем на threejs.org и смотрим исходники примеров трехмерок, там и бродилка простая есть, на понимание. затем идем на nodejs.org и смотрим примеры оттуда, - по сути онлайн-игрулька есть чат с большим количеством системных сообщений между сервером и клиентом, - примеров чатов там хватает